# How to get precise last digit in python decimal module

Tags: python, decimal

I'm trying to create a program that finds the nth digit on the square root of 2 by using the decimal module

√2 = 1.414213(5)6237309504880168872420969807856967187537694…

if the user requests the 8th digit, the program generates 8 digits of √2 (1.4142135) and print the last digit (5)

```
nth_digit_of_sqrt_of_2 = 8  # i wanna find the 8th digit of √2

expected_sqrt_of_2 = "14142135"  # 5 first digits of √2 (no decimal point)
expected_answer =  5 # the last digit
```

but what actually happens:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


getcontext().prec = nth_digit_of_sqrt_of_2 # set precision to 5 digits

decimal_sqrt_of_2 = Decimal('2').sqrt()
decimal_sqrt_of_2 = str(decimal_sqrt_of_2).replace('.', '')  # convert to string and remove decimal point
print(decimal_sqrt_of_2)
# actual_sqrt_of_2 = 14142136
# actual_answer = 6
```

I tried using ROUND_DOWN and ROND_FLOOR but doesn't seems to work either

Comment: Maybe generate 2-3 digits more to avoid rounding altogether

Answer (score 0):

You can get the digits by using:

```
def digit(n):
    from decimal import Decimal
    return str(Decimal('2').sqrt()).replace('.', '')[n-1]
    
digit(8)
#'5'
digit(7)
#'3'
digit(9)
#'6'
```

**Edit:** If you want more digits you can customize your own function.

```
def sqrut(x, digits):
    x = x * (10**(2*digits))
    prev = 0
    next = 1 * (10**digits)
    while prev != next:
        prev = next
        next = (prev + (x // prev)) >> 1
    return str(next)
```

suppose you want 1000 digits in squareroot of 2 you can get by

```
print(sqrut(2, 1000))

'14142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727350138462309122970249248360558507372126441214970999358314132226659275055927557999505011527820605714701095599716059702745345968620147285174186408891986095523292304843087143214508397626036279952514079896872533965463318088296406206152583523950547457502877599617298355752203375318570113543746034084988471603868999706990048150305440277903164542478230684929369186215805784631115966687130130156185689872372352885092648612494977154218334204285686060146824720771435854874155657069677653720226485447015858801620758474922657226002085584466521458398893944370926591800311388246468157082630100594858704003186480342194897278290641045072636881313739855256117322040245091227700226941127573627280495738108967504018369868368450725799364729060762996941380475654823728997180326802474420629269124859052181004459842150591120249441341728531478105803603371077309182869314710171111683916581726889419758716582152128229518488472'
```

Now, if you want 8th digit then:

```
print(sqrut(2, 1000)[8-1])
#'5'

#9th digit then:
print(sqrut(2, 1000)[9-1])
#'6'

#nth digit then:
print(sqrut(2, 1000)[n-1])
```

Comment: it only works if n <= 28 as Decimal  module precision have only 28 digits by default

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

nth_digit_of_sqrt_of_2 = 8
getcontext().prec = nth_digit_of_sqrt_of_2 + 1 # set precision to n+1 digits

decimal_sqrt_of_2 = Decimal('2').sqrt()
decimal_sqrt_of_2 = str(decimal_sqrt_of_2).replace('.', '')  # convert to string and remove decimal point
print(int(str(decimal_sqrt_of_2)[nth_digit_of_sqrt_of_2 - 1]))
```